# Hover Slideshow Repositioning Error not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, colorbox

This slideshow works great in all my browsers except IE. Can someone tell me why its moving all crazy like?

LIVE EXAMPLE HERE:
http://newsite.702wedding.com/cheap-las-vegas-weddingssss.asp

Comment: When I looked at your site with FireBug, DOM ready was fired at 7.82s. That's catastrophic (contrast it with 396ms for google). You need some optimizations on this site if you want to make it usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kill two birds with one stone here:

- Fix the weird image resizing issue.
- Fix the images moving down when you hover over them and the controls become visible.

To do this, add `position: absolute` to `#vig`.

You will then need to sort out the actual position of the buttons.

Let me know if you need help with this.